# Empty tuple in sml

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am writing a function that's supposed to return `a list of 'a * 'a tuples`  .I actually use it only for integers though. The thing is , when I am writing the base case in my pattern matching I don't know how to make it compile: I tried things like

```
fun myf [] = []
fun myf [] = [()]
fun myf [] = [(NONE, NONE)]
```

None, of the 3 above did the work .
I found nothing by searching the web.

Comment: The first one _is_ an empty list, which could be of type `'a * 'a list`. The second one is a list of type `unit`, which obviously doesn't match the type you need.  The third is a value of type `'a option * 'b option list`, and again, this doesn't match the type you need.

Comment: What is the expected output when `[]` is supplied to the function?

Comment: If the first didn't work, the problem lies in how you combined it with the rest of your code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Your question is regarding "returning", but you are attempting pattern-matching, which typically will be happening on the arguments of your function. And the whole construction of the question is misleading. Is it that you want to pattern match against inputs of type "list of pairs" or what type of values are you expecting in the input?? Because returning a ('int * int) list is is as simple as simply writing [(1, 2)] or any list construction whose element is of type (int * int) aka pair of ints.

Comment: Take for example the following: 

fun myf x = if x = 0 then [] else [(1, 2)];   
or 
fun myf x = if x = 0 then [] else (1, 2)::[];

It's that easy to return a ('a * 'a) list.. :-) Unless, if you can help us with what is it that you are expecting in place of 'x'(the parameter)?

Comment: Also, an empty tuple will not have type consistency with a pair.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you get to "an empty tuple" is the unit value: `()`. But a list of unit values will only be able to have different lengths, not different values in each element. If you want *either* an empty value, or some specific value, you can use the `'a option` type, e.g.:

```
fun maximum [] = NONE
  | maximum [x] = SOME x
  | maximum (x::y::xs) = let val z = Int.max (x, y) in maximum (z::xs) end
```

If you want a list of `'a option` values, you may want to consider why you care about gathering multiple `NONE` values in different positions. There are use-cases for this, but often you may be happy without them, too.